find the recursive definition of the formula 6n^2-n
The question is to find the recursive definition of the sequence {an} where n = 1, 2, ...
The sequence is defined by an = 6n2 - 3n
I'm not sure how to approach it. The teacher wants us to express an as a combination of an-1 by using adding zeros.
For example:

an = 6n2 - 3n
a1 = 3
an-1 = ...
Using a bunch of laws to get an = an-1 + #

 for example Using the definition an = 4n, we derive:

a1 = 4; and
an-1 = 4(n - 1) = 4n - 4.

So, we have:

an = 4n (definition of an)
= 4n + 4 - 4 (adding zero (4 - 4))
= (4n - 4) + 4 (associative/commutative laws)
= an-1 + 4 (definition of an-1)

Recursive Definition: a1 = 4 and an = an-1 + 4, for all n ≥ 2.

The question as you have written it is poorly worded. I think you have the sequence defined by, $a_n = 6n^2 - 3n.$ And they want you to compute $a_n - a_{n-1},$ which would give you the recursive "definition" of $(a_n).$ Do you agree with this?

i have fixed the formating they do not want me to compute an-an-1 rather they want me to derive an-1 from an somehow

But surely $ a_{n}= a_{n-1} + f(n) $ is equivalent to $a_{n} - a_{n-1} = f(n).$ Now, our goal is to find a polynomial expression for $f(n).$ So...  $a_n = 6n^2 - 3n, $ and $ a_{n-1} = 6(n-1)^2 - 3(n-1)=...$. Therefore $f(n) = a_{n} - a_{n-1} = 6n^2 - 3n - (6(n-1)^2 - 3(n-1)) = ...$ Once you have a polynomial expression for $f(n),$ you can then finally write, $ a_{n}= a_{n-1} + f(n) $ where $f(n)$ is replaced with it's polynomial expression.

The question is very unclearly worded. However, I think you're asking how to get the recursive definition of the sequence $a_n = 6n^2 - 3n$ in the form $a_n = a_{n-1}+f(n)$.
Well, just take the difference $a_n - a_{n-1}$. It's that easy:
$a_n - a_{n-1} = 6n^2 - 3n - [6(n-1)^2 - 3(n-1)] = 12n - 9$
To determine $a_0$ just substitute $n=1$ in the expression $a_{n-1}+12n-9$ and solve the equation:
$a_0 + 12 - 9 = 6 \cdot 1^2 - 3 \cdot 1 \implies a_0 = 0$
So the sequence can be recursively defined as:
$\begin{cases}a_0 = 0\\ a_n = a_{n-1} + 12n - 9\end{cases}$

Or even more recursively, $a_n = 3 a_{n-1} - 3 a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}$

@RobertIsrael sure, that is a very fine solution. I was sticking to the request of something in the form $a_n = a_{n-1} + #$, as the author specified in the question. I assumed that "#" was referring to some function in explicit dependemce on $n$.
